# How to use Reactive's WhenActivated in a base Content Page

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I'm using a reactive content page base but how do I access something from a base viewmodel?  Do I have to use the object of the actual base viewmodel?

I've tried something like this but intellisense is barking at me for obvious reasons.  How do I access the a command I added to my base veiwmodel that all my view models extend.  The base viewmodel is called "BaseViewModel".

Also, can you have .WhenActivated in your ContentPageBase as well as in your Content Pages or does this mess something up?

```
 public class ContentPageBase<TViewModel> : ReactiveContentPage<TViewModel>, IContentPageBase where TViewModel : class
{
    protected IBindingTypeConverter bindingDoubleToIntConverter;
    private Subject<Unit> clearMessageQueueSubject;

    public ContentPageBase() : base()
    {
        clearMessageQueueSubject = new Subject<Unit>();
        bindingDoubleToIntConverter = (IBindingTypeConverter)App.Container.Resolve<IDoubleToIntConverter>();

        this
            .WhenActivated(
                disposables =>
                {       
                   // VS complains when I try to use TViewModel as first param                 
                    clearMessageQueueSubject.InvokeCommand(TViewModel, x => x.ClearMessageQueueCommand).DisposeWith(disposables);
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraint must be `where TViewModel : BaseViewModel` in order to the .Net compiler identify the type correctly.

And maybe you'll need an instance of this type on you `Invoke` method.

Answer (score 1):

based on Diego Rafael Souza's answer I got it working by doing the following:

```
public class ContentPageBase<TViewModel> : ReactiveContentPage<TViewModel>, IContentPageBase where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    protected IBindingTypeConverter bindingDoubleToIntConverter;
    public Subject<Unit> clearMessageQueueSubject;

    //protected Settings setting;
    public ContentPageBase() : base()
    {
        clearMessageQueueSubject = new Subject<Unit>();
        bindingDoubleToIntConverter = (IBindingTypeConverter)App.Container.Resolve<IDoubleToIntConverter>();


        this
            .WhenActivated(
                disposables =>
                {                        
                    clearMessageQueueSubject.InvokeCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.ClearMessageQueueCommand).DisposeWith(disposables);
                });
    }
```

... another option, not necessarily recommended:

```
public class ContentPageBase<TViewModel> : ReactiveContentPage<TViewModel>, IContentPageBase where TViewModel : class
{
    protected IBindingTypeConverter bindingDoubleToIntConverter;
    public Subject<Unit> clearMessageQueueSubject;

    public ContentPageBase() : base()
    {
        clearMessageQueueSubject = new Subject<Unit>();
        bindingDoubleToIntConverter = (IBindingTypeConverter)App.Container.Resolve<IDoubleToIntConverter>();


        this
            .WhenActivated(
                disposables =>
                {                        
                    clearMessageQueueSubject.InvokeCommand((IBaseViewModel)this.ViewModel, x => x.ClearMessageQueueCommand).DisposeWith(disposables);
                });
    }
```

Comment: In your second example, if the `TViewModel` does not implement `IBaseViewModel`, you'll get an `ArgumentNullException` when the command is invoked.  Why not add that interface as a constraint on the `TViewModel` (`where TViewModel : class, IBaseViewModel`)?

Comment: @EugenePawlik I thought it was always best to use an interface whenever possible.  Is this wrong?

Comment: Sorry, you'll get an `InvalidCastException` if it doesn't implement `IBaseViewModel`.  It is good to use interfaces, but the constraint in your second example only says "the type used as the generic argument has to be a class".  It doesn't specify anything about what that class has to look like...  By adding that interface to the list of constraints on the type parameter, you guarantee that any type provided implements that interface. Like:

`public class ContentPageBase<TViewModel> : ReactiveContentPage<TViewModel>, IContentPageBase where TViewModel : class, IBaseViewModel`

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd even want to cast to IBaseViewModel to be honest. Just make sure you know TViewModel is of the right type by specifying a constraint. And don't use interfaces just because... They have a reason to exist, but if you never even plan te create new implementations, why bother?